# how come the background pic is hidden

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a good background photo and I found the one in the following link interesting:
[pic link](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fprofile%2Fview%3FauthType%3Dname%26ut%3D3Xrrhpmtu4SmA1%26id%3D301266328%26authToken%3DZ4yT%26fromEmail%3D%26trk%3Deml-comm_invm-b-pro_txt-remind2013%26invAcpt%3D141352711_I5966171545599516672_500)

So as usual I tried to inspect the element to get the image and save it but surprisingly I could not find any reference or link to the background picture and now my question is what trick do they use to hide that because usuaslly we use : background-image:/pic and then the pic would be accessible to everyone via inspect element but I am so confused about this !!!!!!

Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/apps/uas/photo_splash_signin_1141x759_v4.jpg ? this is a poor question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url("/scds/common/u/images/apps/uas/photo_splash_signin_1141x759_v4.jpg") no-repeat fixed center bottom transparent

It's not hidden.You haven't checked it properly.